# Projective normality of residual pencils on a general curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a general curve, say of even genus $g=2s$. Then $C$ has finitely many pencils $|L|$ of degree $\deg L=[g+3]/2=s+1$. Choose one such. The residual series is of degree $\deg(K_C-L)=3s-3$.

Is it always the case that $K_C-L$ is projectively normal, i.e. for all $m>0$, $S^mH^0(K_C-L)\to H^0(mK_C-mL)$ is surjective? (for general $C$)

(Ex. C-4,C-5 in Arbarello et al. "geometry of algebraic curves, vol. I", says that on general $C$ any general linear series of degree $[3g/2]+2$ is projectively normal)

Edit: of course, we need to assume ${s+m \choose m}\geq 1-2s +3m(s-1)$. So, for fixed $s$, I actually want to consider only the values of $m$ satisfying this condition.

Edit: as Jason Starr points out in the comments below this already fails in genus 4. What if we only ask for quadratically normal (i.e. only $m=2$) ? (of course then assuming $g\geq10$)

Comment: That fails for $s$ equal to $2$.  Every non-hyperelliptic curve $C$ of genus $4$ is a complete intersection in $\mathbb{P}^3$ of a unique quadric surface $Q$ and a cubic surface.  If $C$ is general, then $Q$ is smooth, i.e., $Q\cong \mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$.  The two pencils $|L_i|$ of degree $s+1=3$ on $C$ are the restrictions to $C$ of the two projections $\pi_i:Q\to \mathbb{P}^1$.  The residual of $|L_1|$ is $|L_2|$ and vice versa.  In particular, since the residual series does not separate points, that map fails to be surjective for all $m\geq 3$.

Comment: The same sort of thing happens for $s=3$.  The residual linear system $|L'|$ maps the genus $6$ curve $C$ to a plane curve of degree $6$ with $4$ nodes.  So the linear system $|L'|$ fails to separate pairs of points (the pairs mapping to nodes), while $|mL'|$ gives a projective embedding for every $m\geq 3$.  Perhaps your question has a positive answer for $s\geq 4$, since then it is possible that the associated morphism $\phi_{|L'|}:C\to \mathbb{P}^{s-1}$ is an embedding.

Comment: @JasonStarr thank you for the illuminating examples. Do you think it might be true if we stick to $m=2$, i.e. only asking quadratic normality?

Comment: For $s=2$, using the short exact sequence of coherent sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$, $0\to \mathcal{O}(-3,-1)\to \text{pr}_2^*\mathcal{O}(2) \to \mathcal{O}_C(2L_2) \to 0$, it follows that the map is surjective for $m=2$.  For $s=3$, $C\subset \mathbb{P}^5$ is a complete intersection of a quintic Del Pezzo surface and a quadric hypersurface, so a similar computation is possible . . .

Comment: If I recall correctly, Green and Lazarsfeld wrote a paper on the issue of failure of projective normality.  Essentially failure of quadratic normality is the only issue.  As I recall higher m 'come for free' via the bpf pencil trick.

Comment: I'm continuing this as a comment, because I don't have the time to double check my memory, and because my arithmetic may be correct modulo '1/2'.  As I recall, the same paper shows that failure of quadratic normality is equivalent  to there existing a 2e pointed e-1 plane in the projective space given by the embedding of the curve.  So, since the original divisor D is a s+1 pointed (s-1) plane, the question becomes can there exist a $g^{1+e}_{s+1+2e}$ .  Using B-N, and hoping I have my numbers right, I get we need $ (e+2)(g - (s+1+2e) +e+1) \leq g$

Comment: Using $ g= 2s $ and playing around I get that we need to have the inequality $s-2 \leq e $.  For $s=3$ I think (hope !) this recovers what Jason said.  Since we also need $ 2g-2 \geq s+1 + 2e $, we also get the inequality $ 2e \leq 3s- 5 $ .  If my numbers are correct,  this means your question should always fail.  Please double check my, ahem, math.